# How to save a print output with 'for' loop as an array variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, binary

I have a bigger script where at the end I need to change string variable to the binary code. It works and it prints binary code for the given string. I would like to save that binary code as a variable, preferable for example as an array - one char into one position. Unfortunately, no solution came to my mind that would work. I checked several threads about saving print outputs to the variables, but it seems that with the code that I have nothing works properly.

Code below:

```py
import numpy as np

str = "sample"
print(" ".join(f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in str))
```

Things that obviously are not working:

```py
[1] this = print(" ".join(f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in str))
[2] this = np.array(print(" ".join(f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in str)))
```

In the [2] case it doesn't give any error and the variable is saved, but the content of the variable is "ndarray object of numpy module". When I want to open it I see message "object arrays are currently not supported".

Is there any simple solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: `print()` turns its arguments to strings, writes them to `sys.stdout` and returns `None`. What exactly did you expect the array to contain? Why not just use `np.array([f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in str])`, or even `np.array(str.encode("ascii"))`? The latter gives you the bytes as integers, so not stored as strings of `0` and `1` characters.

Comment: k = np.array(str.encode("ascii")) is also empty with the message "bytes48 arrays are currently not supported" unfortunetly. / Oh, I'm sorry, yours comment changed, give me one second to check things.

Comment: Right, so `np.array(list(str.encode("ascii")))` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` returns `None`. Since you don't want to write anything to sys.stdout, you should remove that. Something like this:

```
this = np.array(' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in str))
```

You can even convert it to a `bytearray`:

```
this = np.array(' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(st)))
```

Using `format(...)` makes more sense here. The `'b'` is for binary.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I was so obsessed with printing the results that I couldn't even think of the simple answer like yours first one... Thank you for opening my eyes. Have a nice day!